# How to update highstock with navigator disabled?

Tags: real-time, highcharts

I have a problem with highstock : I update my graph with realtime datas.
It works perfectly when navigator is enabled.

=> [official example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.7.2/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/dynamic-update/)

But when I disable navigator, update is really bugged :

```
...
navigator: {
    enabled: false
},
...
```

=> [Bug example](http://jsfiddle.net/a7AjD/)

Someone has an idea why ?

Answer (score 2):

OK, I found a solution :

```
// Add a point
self.graph.series[index].addPoint([time, parseFloat(values.last)], true, true);

// Update viewport min and max to follow updates
if ( ! self.get('showNavigator') ) {
    var extremes = self.graph.xAxis[0]; 
    self.graph.xAxis[0].setExtremes(extremes.dataMax-(extremes.oldMax-extremes.oldMin), extremes.dataMax) ; 
}
```